# Ruby permutations and threads

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I am trying to calculate all permutations for `["a".."z", "A".."Z", 0..9]` and length `@perm`. So by using `.lazy` I decreased memory usage from 7.5 out of 8GB in my machine but I still have some issues/questions:

```
@perm = 4
@chars = [*"a".."z", *"A".."Z", *0..9]
@total_perm = @chars.size**@perm
@ips = 10000
@total_indexes = 0

@thr = []

puts "@total_perm: #{@total_perm}"

@chars.repeated_permutation(@perm).lazy.map(&:join).each_slice(@ips).with_index do |item, index|

  puts "=========> out_index: #{index}"

    @thr << Thread.new do
      begin
        item.each_with_index do |vitem, vindex|
          @total_indexes += 1
        end
      rescue ThreadError
      end
    end

end

@thr.each {|t| t.join }

puts "=========> total_indexes: #{@total_indexes}"
```

1. Threads are not doing what they should - There is not much performance increase If I use each_slice and slice them down to arrays of 10,000 items, then create a Thread for each one.
2. Memory usage has decreased significantly (7.5GB -> 45MB) but the CPU usage still remains high. Would there be any solution for this ? Maybe limit its usage dynamically ?

Comment: Please use English punctuation when you write in English.

Comment: _"not much performance increase"_ and _"CPU usage still remains high"_ seems contradictory. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well If I request 8 permutations there are 218,340,084,573,246 possibilities and it will take approximately 4570 days. Makes sense ? I don't want it to finish when I will be old :D Distribute it between cores or even machines would decrease the overall time.

Comment: @ChrisV. 1.5 years on a 8-core machine doesn't sound that great, either. I'm curios, why do you want to calculate all these permutations?

Comment: @Stefan to experiment with setups and performance over Ruby. And If possible create a smart hasher or some rainbow tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can read this article [Ruby concurrency and parallelism](https://www.toptal.com/ruby/ruby-concurrency-and-parallelism-a-practical-primer).

In summary, CRuby 1.9>= threads are not 'native'(not green), but because of GIL they can't be parallel. Rubinious and JRuby don't have GIL, so it's an option. Other options are to implement threadpool yourself or use some gems like EventMachine and Celluloid.

Comment: don't forget ruby_concurent. But yeah, you can't use more than CPU at once on MRI, multi-threading on MRI is still good for things that do significant IO, but not for things that are heavily CPU.